# Row-level hyperlink acting funny

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Developing an ASP.NET/MVC5 website. Using jQuery FooTable. For each row in a data-driven table I have some "actions" icons. One of the icons pulls up a "Quick Look" summary table with the persons info in it. Here's what it looks like....

[image]
The Quick Look (eyeball) icon is defined as...

```
<a href="#" title="Quick Look" data-toggle="popover" 
    data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-content="@quicklook">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

The variable @quicklook is defined as....

```
 var quicklook = "<table>" +
    "<tr><td style='width:75px;'>Name:</td><td><b>" + 
    @cust.Value.FirstName + ' ' + @cust.Value.LastName + 
    "</b></td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td>DOB:</td><td><b>" + @cust.Value.DOB + 
    "</b></td></tr>" +
        :
      etc. etc.
```

So, you can see that I'm using razor syntax as well. The pop ups work great UNTIL I select some rows lower on the grid/screen. Then when I click on the button it jumps me to the top of the page and I don't see my "Quick Look" info box. Any ideas why? I suppose it's because the href="#". But, I'm not sure how to get around this. I tried creating an ID with unique row number for each table row and jumping to that in my href, but that didn't work well. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are these options:

1. Define `return: false;` at click event.
2. Define `event.stopPropagation()` at click event.
3. Don't make the eye as a link and use e.g. `<div>` instead.

Comment: I tried both suggestions 1 and 2 in the onclick of the anchor tag, but the same issue still occurs. For lower records when I click it goes to the top of the page. Changing the <a> to a <div> didn't work either. Thanks, but any other ideas?

Comment: Ideally, paste here a sample code or a link to your site.